# Expectation of integration Brownian motion at stopping time.

Tags: stochastic-processes, brownian-motion, stochastic-integrals, stopping-times

Consider the problem:
Let $X_t = \mu t+ \sigma  B_t$ with $\mu, \sigma >0$ where $B_t$ is a standard BM. Fix $\beta>0$, let $\tau = \inf\{t: X_t = \beta\}$. Calculate $$\mathbb{E}\int_0^\tau(\beta - X_t)dt$$
Here's my thought: since $\beta - X_t$ is continuous,
$$\mathbb{E}\int_0^\tau(\beta - X_t)dt = \int_0^\tau\mathbb{E}(\beta - X_t)dt =\int_0^\tau(\beta - \mu t - \sigma\mathbb{E}(B_t))dt = \beta \tau - \frac{1}{2}\mu \tau^2$$
The problemis, I did not use the properties of the stopping time $\tau$. This makes me feel weird.
Can someone please let me know where I made a mistake?

Comment: Left hand side of your equation is a number (expected value) and right hand side of your equation is a random variable (since $\tau$ is a random variable). It means, that you incorrectly solved your problem. You cannot switch the order of integration.

Comment: As @B_B said, the result cannot depend on $\tau$, since the expectation is a number. Now if $X_t$ and $\tau$ were independent then you could do $\int_0^\infty \int_0^t \beta-\mathbb{E}[X_s] \, ds \, d\mathbb{P}(\tau=t)$. But you can't do that, either, because $\tau$ depends on $X_t$. Instead you have to deal with $\mathbb{E}[X_s \mid \tau=t]$, which is not the same thing. Basically what you need is the expectation of a Brownian bridge.

Comment: The evaluation $\Bbb E\int_0^\tau(\beta-\mu t)dt =\beta\Bbb E[\tau]-\mu\Bbb E[\tau^2]/2$ is unassailable. As for the rest
$$
-\sigma\Bbb E\int_0^\tau B_t dt,
$$
you should be able to make some progress by noting that 
$$
\int_0^\tau B_t dt = {1\over 3}B_{\tau}^3-\int_0^\tau B^2_t dB_t.
$$
The stochastic integral $M_u:=\int_0^u B^2_t dB_t$  is a martingale, and $B_\tau=(\beta-\mu\tau)/\sigma$.

Comment: This is very clear. Thank you very much! One thing I want to check is that $M_u$ is a martingale because of the martingale property of stochastic integral, right? Then it implies that the expectation of that part is zero.

Comment: That's right. That's why this helps, actually: it breaks it into a function only of $B_\tau$ (whose vale is known) and a martingale. Do note that you'll need to justify invoking optional stopping in order to conclude that part is zero, though.

Comment: The other route that I can see is to follow what I said, which gives you that $E[X_s \mid \tau=t]=\mu s + \sigma E[B_s \mid \tau=t]$, and now $E[B_s \mid \tau=t]$ is the expectation of a Brownian bridge that starts at $0$ at time $0$ and ends at $\frac{\beta-\mu t}{\sigma}$ at time $t$. Thus you have $\mathbb{E}[X_s \mid \tau=t]=\mu s + \frac{s}{t}(\beta-\mu t)=\frac{s}{t} \beta$. Integrating that from $0$ to $t$ against $s$ gives $\frac{t}{2} \beta$, and so you have $\frac{\beta}{2} E[\tau]$. $E[\tau]$ can be fairly painlessly calculated by solving a second order linear ODE.

Answer (score 6):

Way 1: begin with

$$\mathbb{E} \left [ \int_0^\tau \beta-X_t dt \right ] = \beta \mathbb{E}[\tau]-\frac{\mu}{2} \mathbb{E}[\tau^2]-\sigma \mathbb{E} \left [ \int_0^\tau B_t dt \right ]$$

assuming all these expectations are finite.

We want to simplify the last term. To do that, consider the differential of $Y_t=B_t^3/3$. It is

$$dY_t=B_t^2 dB_t + B_t dt$$

by the Ito formula. Thus

$$\mathbb{E} \left [ \int_0^\tau B_t dt \right ] = \mathbb{E}[Y_\tau]-\mathbb{E} \left [ \int_0^\tau B_t^2 dB_t \right ]$$

and the LHS is the thing we want to get. So we need to look at the two RHS terms. For the first one, by the definition of $\tau$:

$$Y_\tau=\frac{1}{3} \left ( \frac{\beta-\mu \tau}{\sigma} \right )^3.$$

The second term can be shown to be zero provided that we can provided that we can justify applying optional stopping to the martingale $\int_0^t B_t^2 dB_t$. So plugging everything in:

$$\mathbb{E} \left [ \int_0^\tau \beta-X_t dt \right ] = \beta \mathbb{E}[\tau] - \frac{\mu}{2} \mathbb{E}[\tau^2] - \frac{\sigma}{3} \mathbb{E} \left [ \left ( \frac{\beta-\mu \tau}{\sigma} \right )^3 \right ].$$

Thus you need the first three moments of $\tau$ and nothing else in order to finish the problem.

I think you can obtain the MGF of $\tau$ using another martingale technique, which allows you to finish the problem. However $\mathbb{E}[\tau]$ is more easily obtained as we will see below.

Way 2: begin with

$$\mathbb{E} \left [ \int_0^\tau \beta-X_t dt \right ] = \int_0^\infty \mathbb{E} \left [ \int_0^t \beta-X_s ds \mid \tau=t \right ] d\mathbb{P}(\tau=t).$$

Under these assumptions, $B_t$ goes from $0$ to $\frac{\beta-\mu t}{\sigma}$ in time $t$, and so its conditional expected value at time $s$ is $\frac{s}{t} \frac{\beta-\mu t}{\sigma}$ by the properties of the Brownian bridge. Therefore the conditional expected value of $X_s$ is $\mu s + \frac{s}{t}(\beta-\mu t)=\frac{s}{t} \beta$. Therefore

$$\mathbb{E} \left [ \int_0^\tau \beta-X_t dt \right ] = \int_0^\infty \int_0^t (1-s/t) \beta \, ds \, d \mathbb{P}(\tau=t) \\
= \int_0^\infty \frac{\beta}{2} t \, d \mathbb{P}(\tau=t) \\
= \frac{\beta}{2} \mathbb{E}[\tau].$$

I do know how to get the first moment off the top of my head: $\mathbb{E}[\tau]$ is $\lim_{a \to -\infty} u(a,0)$ where

$$\mu \partial_x u(a,x) + \frac{\sigma^2}{2} \partial^2_x u(a,x) = -1 \\
u(a,a)=0 \\
u(a,\beta)=0.$$

The intuition for the derivation of this equation is to write the equation $u(a,x)=h+\int_{\mathbb{R}} u(a,y) d\mathbb{P}(X_h=y \mid X_0=x)$ and then get an estimate of the integral for small $h$, then rearrange and send $h \to 0$.

Now for $\mu \neq 0$ we have

$$u(a,x)=c_1 + c_2 e^{-kx} - x/\mu$$

where $k=2\mu/\sigma^2$. So

$$c_1 + c_2 e^{-ka} = a/\mu \\
c_1 + c_2 e^{-k\beta} = \beta/\mu \\
u(a,0)=c_1+c_2.$$

If $\mu>0$ then we recover $\lim_{a \to -\infty} u(a,0)=\frac{\beta}{\mu}$. If $\mu<0$ then we recover $\lim_{a \to -\infty} u(a,0)=+\infty$.

In the $\mu=0$ case the situation is simpler:

$$u(a,x)=-\frac{1}{\sigma^2} (x-a)(x-\beta)$$

and so $\mathbb{E}[\tau]$ is again $+\infty$.

Thus we find that when $\mu>0$, the desired quantity is $\frac{\beta^2}{2\mu}$, and otherwise it is $+\infty$. Somewhat surprisingly, $\sigma$ does not enter this at all.